# firebase / Sorting doc's by increasing the field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I sort the doc's by increasing the field "time"?
my code

```
    function renderOrder(doc) {
this.afs.collection('values',ref=>ref.OrderBy('time','desc')).valueChanges();
}
button.addEventListener("click", function () {this.afs.collection('values').add({ time: firebase.firestore().FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying increasing the field "time"?

Comment: @ThomasLombart when i creating a doc, the current time is recorded in the "time" field; these documents should be sorted by time of addition (
Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting of document's in the firebase firestore is done by firebase.If you want get the document based on the time of creation you have to create a field ,let's say time and store the serverTimestamp. Now when querying your document you can use the orderBy clause to get the document.

To add the documnet:

```
this.afs.collection('values').add({
time:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

To retrieve the documnet:

```
this.afs.collection('values',ref=>ref.OrderBy('time','desc')).valueChanges();
```

this will give you an Observable of documents.On subscription you will get an array of documents,where the first element of array is lastly added document

Comment: when i run the function it displays an error "Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined"

Comment: please try with this one,  this.afs.collection('values').add({
time:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});

Comment: if the issue solved please accept and up vote my answer,so others can easily find out solution

Comment: when i run the function it displays an error "Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined"

Comment: which function.?

Comment: when i press the button it should work "time:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()", but an error occurs

Comment: did you imported the firebase.firestore module..?

Comment: Yes, I imported

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: var db = firebase.firestore();   button.addEventListener("click", function () {db.collection('values').add({ time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});  this code will add new item in to the collection 'value' with a random id

Comment: great, timestamp added, how i can sort all doc's

Comment: you don't have to do anything to sort documents.It will done by firebase;If you want get the document based on the time stamp, you have to query according to the above code given in the answer [https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries]

Comment: sorry, but i dont undersand how i can sort.
I write 'firestore.collection('values').orderBy('time', 'desc');',
but this do not work, and your answer do not work too.(error:FirebaseError: Function Firestore.collection() requires 1 argument, but was called with 2 arguments.)